# How to get access to Current view model methods from Shell.js

Tags: shell, durandal

I have a button in shell.html, on click of that button I need to post the current view model.

I can determine the current view model's Module Id,  but how can I get a reference to it so that I can invoke its methods from Shell.js

For eg, if my current view model has a method called "SubmitApplication" 
I would like to call or trigger this method from Shell.js on click of the button in Shell.html

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Durandal's event system for cross module communication.
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe.html

By default `app` has event capabilities included, which would allow you to do something along the following line:

#### shell.js

```
submitOnClick: function(){
    app.trigger('application:submit', payload);
}
```

#### viewmodel

```
app.on('application:submit').then(function(payload){
    //do something with payload
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I also thought the same but not able to get it working, I am using typescript to do the same. would you have some typescript equivalent code.

Comment: Good to hear. Please add your solution as an answer and accept it in couple of days. That way others could benefit from it.

Comment: I just used your code as it is, in view model with typescript I did some thing like this  var sub =              app.on('application:submit').then(function(payload){
    //do something with payload
}); it works but may not be very Typescript kind of code

Comment: Every valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript, so that should be fine. If all is working accept this as an answer, to get the question closed.